# How to simulate from priors with pymc3

Tags: bayesian, simulation, pymc

I'd like to simulate y from the prior (not from the posterior) with `pymc3`.

I first defined the model:

```
import pymc3 as pm

with pm.Model() as m:
    mu = pm.Normal('mu', mu=0, sd=10)
    sigma = pm.Uniform('sigma', lower=0, upper=10)
    y = pm.Normal('y', mu=mu, sd=sigma)
    trace = pm.sample(1000, tune=1000)
```

Then I tried to get 10 simulated y from the model with:

```
y_pred = pm.sample_ppc(trace, 10, m, size=10)
```

But result comes out empty. I searched through the documentation but I didn't find a relevant example. Is it possible to do it with `pymc3`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `trace` contains the sample from the prior when no observed is associated with the model definition. However, this could fail sometimes. We are currently working on a `sample_prior` function that would make this process easier and more straightforward: https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/pull/2876

Comment: If I understood correctly, I can get a prior sample for `y` using `[i['y'] for i in trace.points()]`

Comment: Did this ever get confirmed @gc5 ? Interested to know for my own project

Comment: @SamComber Unfortunately not, but it looked reasonable so I accepted it. If you happen to confirm it please add to this answer.

Comment: @gc5 It does not always work, either you wait for the PR to merge, or use the code in this notebook for now https://github.com/junpenglao/Planet_Sakaar_Data_Science/blob/master/Miscellaneous/Test_sample_prior.ipynb